# measure execution time and stop waiting if too long in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to measure execution time of `funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime` function.

```
func measureTime(expectedMs float64) (ok bool) {
    t1 := time.Now()
    funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime()
    t2 := time.Now()
    diff := t2.Sub(t1)
```

The measuring is fine when  `funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime` works faster than I expected. But if it works slower than `expectedMs`  the measuring will not stop right after expected amount of milliseconds passed.

Is it possible to stop time measuring when `funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime` works longer than `expectedMs` without waiting `funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime` to finish?

In other words, `measureTime(200)` should return in `200 ms` anyway with a good or bad result.

I guess I should use channels and then somehow cancel waiting for a channel. But how to do it exactly?

Full code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

// random number between min and max
func random(min, max int) int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    return rand.Intn(max-min) + min
}

// sleeps for a random milliseconds amount between 200 and 1000
func funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime() {
    millisToSleep := random(200, 1000)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Sleeping for %d milliseconds", millisToSleep))
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(millisToSleep))
}

// measures execution time of a function funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime
// if expectedMs < actual execution time, it's ok.
// if expectedMs milliseconds passed and funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime
// still did not finish execution it should return
// without waiting for funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime
func measureTime(expectedMs float64) (ok bool) {
    t1 := time.Now()
    funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime()
    t2 := time.Now()
    diff := t2.Sub(t1)
    actualMs := diff.Seconds() * 1000
    ok = actualMs < expectedMs
    fmt.Println(actualMs)
    return
}

// prints results: Ok or too late
func printTimeResults(ok bool) {
    if ok {
        fmt.Println("Ok")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Too late")
    }
}

func main() {
    printTimeResults(measureTime(200))  // expect it to finish in 200 ms anyway
    printTimeResults(measureTime(1000)) // expect it to finish in 1000 ms anyway
}
```

Output:

```
Sleeping for 422 milliseconds
424.11895200000004
Too late
Sleeping for 422 milliseconds
425.27274900000003
Ok
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/YP6GxoiSbg)

Comment: It's possible to stop *waiting* as you describe, but you can't kill a goroutine. You'd have to make your func check for a quit signal (or, if it's doing network calls, set a read/write timeout) if you actually want the func to stop.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: don't re-seed the PRNG. Seeding is normally only done **once** (unless you explicitly want/need to restart a sequence of random numbers from some other seed). In particular, since you've chosen to use `time.Now().Unix()` your "random" function will **always** return **the exact same value** until your clock ticks over to a new second! (I'd just use `func init() { rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano()) }` in the main package or put that line in `main` itself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't cancel a goroutine, unless you design it to be canceled. You can short circuit your timing function, by using a channel to signal the completion of the function being timed:

```
func measureTime(expectedMs float64) (ok bool) {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    t1 := time.Now()

    go func() {
        funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime()
        close(done)
    }()

    select {
    case <-done:
        ok = true
    case <-time.After(time.Duration(expectedMs) * time.Millisecond):
    }

    fmt.Println(time.Since(t1))
    return ok

}
```

Comment: Does that **really** guarantee the timer will immediately stop ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret: it guarantees that `measureTime` will immediately stop. You can't stop `funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime`. It's blocking without a cancellation api of any sort, so it has to run to completion.

Comment: Are you sure there's this guarantee when `funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime` doesn't realease the CPU ? Can you demonstrate it in the playground ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret: Go does have a mostly preemptive scheduler with `GOMAXPROCS > 1`. However, if you run more function-with-busy-loops than you have threads, then it will cause problems. That's more of an implementation detail however, depending on the scheduler.

Comment: @DenysSéguret -- this should do what JimB claims ([the spec for `select` might help show why](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)). If you're convinced it won't, you can build a program to show it. Otherwise, the asker will probably try it and sort it out that way.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: Worst case scenario: http://play.golang.org/p/va5l5_tDqN. You will want to run it locally with `GOMAXPROCS >= 3`. You may also need to adjust the `for` loop to get a reasonable completion time.

Answer (score 3):

Extending JimB's example a little with the design I've personally followed for async background workers. I would say in most cases it's unacceptable to launch a go routine without passing an abort channel... All of your async methods should accept one as an argument or have one defined on their receiving type so you can actually control execution. fyi there are libraries for this, here's a simple one an old colleague of mine made; https://github.com/lytics/squaredance

If your program does not have an abort path for every goroutine you're probably going to face significant quality issues sooner or later. Also, for applications that are doing any heavy lifting in a goroutine, you will likely not be able to gracefully stop and start your application.

```
func measureTime(expectedMs float64) (ok bool) {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    abort := make(chan struct{})
    t1 := time.Now()

    go func() {
        funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime(abort)
        close(done)
    }()

    select {
    case <-done:
        ok = true
    case <-time.After(time.Duration(expectedMs) * time.Millisecond):
        // after signals here when the duration is reached so I close abort
        close(abort)
    }

    fmt.Println(time.Since(t1))
    return ok

}


funcWithUnpredictiveExecutionTime(abort) {
     for {
        select {
           // doing work in here
           case abort:
              // except here, we clean up and return
        }
     }
}
```